# JavaScript: Expand area on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

What I'm trying to do is make it so that, when a user clicks in the textarea, it expands the div to show the 'Post' button.

Here's a picture of what I mean:
[image]

So, when the user clicks in the textbox area, I need the background div to expand and show the 'Post' button.

Here's the JSFiddle I started: [**http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/6018/**](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/6018/)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="well">
    <textarea style="width:462px" placeholder="Comment..."></textarea>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Post</button>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
textarea {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.btn {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.container {
  margin:20px 0 0 20px;
}

.well {
  width: 476px;
  padding: 12px;
}
```

I have no JavaScript experience, but I think this is a simple enough project to look at when finished to be able to understand the basics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following to your markup and styling and include the script.

**HTML**

```
    <button  class="btn btn-primary btn-toggle" type="button">Post</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn-toggle{
    display: none;    
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$("textarea").click(function(){
   $(".btn-toggle").slideDown();
});

$(document).click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    if($(e.target).parents(".well").length == 0){
        $(".btn-toggle").slideUp();
    }
});
```

This segment of Javascript binds click event handlers to the `textarea` and the `document`.  The event handler bound to the `textarea` simply slides down the `button` to make it visible.

The event handler bound to the `document` is fired on every click on the page since the click events propagate up the `DOM` to the `document`.  Once the `document` fires the event, the handler checks to see if the `target` (aka element clicked) has a parent inside the `well`.  If it does we do not perform any actions since we do not want to hide the button when the user clicks inside the `textarea` or the `button` itself.  If the click is outside of the well we call the `slideup` function on the button to hide it in a stylish manner.

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/6025/

Comment: Ha, I took the complicated way: http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/MgcDU/6021/. However mine has an animation.

Comment: Is there a way to make it expand without it being instant? Like, actually show an animation of it expanding? Also, if you click away, can you make it expand back up?

Comment: Instead of `show` you could use `slideDown`. See updated fiddle.

Comment: Alright, thanks. One more thing, if I click outside of the div, how can I make it hide the button again?

Comment: @ErikFischer See updated fiddle and javascript.  You may need to make those selectors a little more specific depending on how you will use this.

Comment: Can you explain the JS?

Comment: @Seth see explanation. In the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Kevin's answer is the one you want, but I was just feeling experimental with some CSS I had, so I just wanted to post it. This is a `fadeInDown` button. You may want to host the CSS on your website. I just used some code I had. You can change this fiddle to fadeIn or something else (just search Google for animate.css). http://jsfiddle.net/shaansingh/MgcDU/6024/embedded/result/